# Code not moving past Read

Tags: pascal

I'm having a problem with my code. It starts fine but when asking to get input from the user at the start it will not move onto the if statement. How can I fix this. I've tried heaps to get around this and eventually got it to read data but continually say that it is invalid.

```
PROGRAM AT3 (input, output);
uses crt, math;
CONST
    band6 = 90;
    band5 = 80;
    band4 = 70;
    band3 = 60;
    band2 = 50;
VAR
    Studname : array of string;
    studmark : array of integer;
    flag : boolean;
    studinfo : text;
    input : string;
    count : integer;
    num : integer;
        input2: integer;
    highmark, lowmark : integer;
    median, average : integer;

BEGIN
    lowmark := 100;
    highmark := 0;
    median := 0;
    ASSIGN (Studinfo, 'ExamResults.txt');
    flag := false;
    WRITELN('welcome to the Band generator.');
        WRITELN('To enter student results, please enter the number of students. To see class statistics, please type zzz. To clear the screen type clear screen. And to exit the program, type exit');
    While flag = false DO
        ReadLN (input);
        IF input = 'zzz' THEN
            WHILE not EOF(Studinfo) DO
            BEGIN
                WRITELN(studinfo);
            END;
        IF input = 'exit' THEN
            Flag := true;
                IF input = 'clear screen' THEN
                        CLRSCR
                ELSE
                    if input2 <> 0 THEN
                        num := input2
                ELSE
                WRITELN('Please enter a valid number.');
        FOR count := 0 to num-1 DO
            BEGIN
            WRITELN('Please enter name of student', count);
            read(studname[count]);
            WRITE(studinfo, studname[count]);
            WRITELN('Please enter mark of student', count, 'out of 100 (nearest whole number)');
            read(studmark[count]);              write(studinfo, studmark[count]);
            IF studmark[count] >=band6 THEN
                WRITELN(studinfo, 'band6');
            IF studmark[count] >=band5 THEN
                WRITELN(studinfo, 'band5');
            IF studmark[count] >=band4 THEN
                WRITELN(studinfo, 'band4');
            IF studmark[count] >=band3 THEN
                WRITELN(studinfo, 'band3');
            IF studmark[count] >=band2 THEN
                WRITELN(studinfo, 'band2');
            IF studmark[count] <band2 THEN
                WRITELN(studinfo, 'band1');
            IF studmark[count] >= highmark THEN
                highmark := studmark[count];
            IF studmark[count] <= lowmark THEN
                lowmark := studmark[count];
            END;
        median := highmark MOD 2;

    CLOSE(studinfo);
END.
```

Comment: "it will not move onto the if statement"  Which `if` statement do you mean, exactly?  Btw, there are several other problems with your code, e.g. your "Assign(Studinfo,  'ExamResults.txt')"  should be followed immediately by "Rewrite(Studinfo)".  Also, what version of Pascal are you using?

Comment: Hmmm... this code looks asthonishingly like the code written by user **LeCarloVC** (and then removed again), yesterday. It also had the same problems and this `if mark/band` thing. Also used uppercase keywords (most of the time) and even this `'zzz'` = end of program idea..

Comment: Indentation alone does not define blocks in Pascal. You need `begin` and `end` for multi-statement blocks.

Comment: The piece of code `if studmark[count] >=band6 then             writeln(studinfo, 'band6'); if studmark[count] >=band5 then                writeln(studinfo, 'band5');` does not achieve what you want.  `if studmark[count] >= band6`, it is **also** `>= band5`, `>= band4`, etc. Either use `if ... else if ... else if ...` or use a `case` statement.

Comment: My fingers are itching to re-write the code and correct **all** mistakes (and provide proper formatting), but then you don't learn. Note that if you format properly, your code is easier to read, not only for others, but also for you. That way, you might see some of the errors already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Questions like this often attract a comment like "SO is not a homework-doing
service."  This q is a bit exceptional because there is no polite way I can think
of to describe it.  It has all the signs of having been written by someone who
doesn't really know what they are doing - but don't despair, we were all beginners once!

I'm not going to rewrite all your code for you - because you won't learn anything from that - but the following should at least give
you a functional main loop which you can then complete yourself and embellish as necessary.

The main thing I've fixed is the sequence of actions in the loop - the original
was a complete muddle, to put it mildly.  I've added various comments enclosed in braces {}.
There is a more recent style of comments that uses // but I don't know what flavour
of Pascal you're using.

Code:

```
const
    band6 = 90;
    band5 = 80;
    band4 = 70;
    band3 = 60;
    band2 = 50;
    ArraySize = 20;  { to set explicit array sizes }
var
    studname : array[1..ArraySize] of string;
    studmark : array[1..ArraySize] of integer;
    flag : boolean;
    studinfo : text;
    kbdinput : string; { to avoid name clash with program Input param}
    count : integer;
    num : integer;
    {input2: integer; not used}
    highmark,
    lowmark : integer;
    median, average : integer;

begin
    lowmark := 100;
    highmark := 0;
    median := 0;
    assign (studinfo, 'c:\temp\examresults.txt'); { always use full path for file name }
    Rewrite(studinfo);  { set studinfo in the state to allow writing to the file}

    flag := false;
    writeln('welcome to the band generator.');
        writeln('to enter student results, please enter the number of students when prompted.');
    while flag = false do
    begin
        write('please enter a valid number of students. ');
        readln(num);
        for count := 1 to num do { not change of start and stop values}
        begin
          write('please enter name of student #', count, ' followed by [Enter] ');
          readln(studname[count]);
          write(studinfo, studname[count]);

          write('please enter mark of student #', count, ' out of 100 (nearest whole number) followed by [Enter] ');
          readln(studmark[count]);
          write(studinfo, studmark[count]);
        end;
{
            if studmark[count] >=band6 then
                writeln(studinfo, 'band6');
            if studmark[count] >=band5 then
                writeln(studinfo, 'band5');
            if studmark[count] >=band4 then
                writeln(studinfo, 'band4');
            if studmark[count] >=band3 then
                writeln(studinfo, 'band3');
            if studmark[count] >=band2 then
                writeln(studinfo, 'band2');
            if studmark[count] <band2 then
                writeln(studinfo, 'band1');
            if studmark[count] >= highmark then
                highmark := studmark[count];
            if studmark[count] <= lowmark then
                lowmark := studmark[count];
            end;
        median := highmark mod 2;
}

      writeln('to see class statistics, please type zzz. to clear the screen type zzz and to exit the program, type exit');
      readln (kbdinput);
      if kbdinput = 'zzz' then
      {  The following does nothing useful
          while not eof(studinfo) do
          begin
              writeln(studinfo);
          end;
      }
      ;
      if kbdinput = 'exit' then
          flag := true
      else
        if kbdinput = 'clear screen' then
          {clrscr;'}

      close(studinfo);
    end;
end.
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at your line:

```
While flag = false DO
        ReadLN (input);
```

Flag is never false so it reads forever. You are having problems with your begin/end blocks.

Comment: `Flag` is always `false`, you mean. But `if input = 'exit'` it is set to true. That should stop the loop.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis In the OP's posted code, the `if input = 'exit'` isn't within the scope of the `while` body. The `while` body is missing the `begin`/`end`.

Comment: @lurker: Ah yes, another mistake in the code. Too many for the code to make sense at all.